# What is the default apache2 log format and where is defined such default?

Tags: 12.04, configuration, apache2, logging

I review (a fast reading) [Apache Module mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) and can't figure out what is the apache2 default log format and where is defined it. Any idea?

Note that what is on

> /etc/apache2/conf.d/other-vhosts-access-log

is not a default option but a global option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clearly stated in the documetation for the [TransferLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#transferlog) statement:

> This directive has exactly the same arguments and effect as the CustomLog directive, with the exception that it does not allow the log format to be specified explicitly or for conditional logging of requests. Instead, the log format is determined by the most recently specified LogFormat directive which does not define a nickname. Common Log Format is used if no other format has been specified.

Go on to the [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) statement:

> **Default:**  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"

So if a `TransferLog` statement is given without any `LogFormat` statement the output format is as described above.

If also the `TransferLog` statment is missing no *access log* is written.

Comment: Thanks, but still can't read anything about TransferLog default, I mean, are you saying that if no CustomLog is specified, the TransferLog directive is in charge even it is not specified? If that is the case, where do you read that? cos TransferLog hasn't a default section defined. Thanks again.

Comment: If no TransferLog is defined, it is not written.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 16.04, you can find the global configuration file here:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Therein it defines some [`LogFormat` directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#LogFormat).

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

The out-of-the-box virtual host configuration file is here:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

And inside you will find that it declares:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

The `combined` alias refers to the second `LogFormat` in the aforementioned global config:

```
"%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Default LogFormat is indeed really

```
Default: LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

But the log format apache uses by default (on Debian distro at least) is:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

Comment: This has changed ever so slightly for Ubuntu 16.04 from `%b` *"Size of response in bytes, excluding HTTP headers. In CLF format, i.e. a '-' rather than a 0 when no bytes are sent."* to now `%O` *"Bytes sent, including headers. May be zero in rare cases such as when a request is aborted before a response is sent. You need to enable mod_logio to use this."*